# Weird behavior of JSF p:dataTable (first entry wrong in p:columns)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have on a page two `p:dataTable`. The left one is mainly used for selection

```
<p:dataTable id="leftTable" var="item" value="#{bean.items}"
             selection="#{bean.item}" selectionMode="single">
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":rightTable" listener="#{bean.select}"/>  
  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />  
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

This is fairly simple and works fine. The *rightTable* is a more complex one, this is a simplified example:

```
<p:dataTable id="rightTable" var="row" value="#{bean.rows}">
  <p:columns var="col" value="#{bean.cols}">  
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.map[row.id][col.id]}"/>
  </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Well, this also works fine. Now I implemented a `composite component` to replace the *leftTable*. This component also has `selection` and `select` attributes and in general is works, too. The same method like from `p:dataTable` is called and also the correct *item* is set.

**But**, and this is really a nasty thing: If I use my custom component, **always** the value in the first cell (column 0, row 0) is `null`. The values are taken from a `Map<Long,Map<Long,String>>` and I verified that the value for the specific `row.id,col.id` is set after the method is called.

I'm completely clueless stump with this issue and expect that it's really hard to answer this question and really appreciate if someone can even help me to **debug** this issue in more detail.

**Upate 1**:
By request I checked the `#{row.id},#{col.id}`:

```
95,626 | 95,528
96,527 | 96,528
97,527 | 97,528
```

In the first cell the *col.id* is wrong. It should be `527` but is actual `626` (it's the value of the previous request). Why does this happen? How can I get the correct value?

**Update 2**: This is my component:

```
<composite:interface componentType="my.MenuDmClick">
  <composite:attribute name="actionListener" required="true"
        method-signature="void listener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)"/>
  <composite:attribute name="selection"/>
  <composite:attribute name="update/>
  <composite:attribute name="dm"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
  <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{cc.attrs.dm.wrappedData}">
  <li>
    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{cc.actionListener(item)}"
                   update="#{cc.attrs.update}">
      <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
    </p:commandLink>
  </li>
  </ui:repeat>
</composite:implementation>
```

And this is the backing bean:

```
@FacesComponent(value="my.MenuDmClick")
public class MenuDmClick extends UINamingContainer
{
  public void actionListener(Object ejb)
  {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ValueExpression mSelection = this.getValueExpression("selection");

    if(mSelection!=null){mSelection.setValue(context.getELContext(), ejb);}
    else{throw new PropertyNotFoundException("'selection' must be a ValueExpression!");}

    MethodExpression ajaxEventListener =
         (MethodExpression) getAttributes().get("actionListener");
    ajaxEventListener.invoke(context.getELContext(), new Object[] {});
  }
}
```

Comment: When you use selectable `dataTable` you should provide `rowKey` to some unique property of your model bean, for example it can be `rowKey="#{item.value}"`. Try with this and see what's happening.

Comment: With the selectable `dataTable` I have no problems. It happens wen I use my own composite:component. The used id's (long) are unique.

Comment: Add print of `#{row.id},#{col.id}` near `h:outputText` and see are the values as expected.

Comment: Great advise. I've done this (see updated question). The _col.id_ is wrong for the first row ... wyhever ...

Comment: This really seems like the problem might be in the managed bean, `bean`, that contains the values.

Comment: how do you call this composite component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the usual stuff like

- ui:repeat and c:forEach
- immediate=true/false

I came across `process=@this` ... and it works like a charm!

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="#{cc.attrs.dm.wrappedData}">
  <li>
    <p:commandLink process="@this"
        actionListener="#{cc.actionListener(item)}" update="#{cc.attrs.update}">
      <h:outputText value="#{item.round.name}"/>
    </p:commandLink>
  </li>
</c:forEach>
```